# hidden vertical scrollbar for the middle column in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar

I need to make the middle column scrollable and also want to keep the scroll bar hidden, i have set up fiddle example http://fiddle.jshell.net/DTcHh/5842/\
 by default it show the scroll-bar in default view for desktop version and when you resize the window using using `Web Developer --> Responsive design view` then it show same toolbar as transparent vertical scroll-bar.

Is there a way i can keep it hidden without removing the scroll functionality.

Screenshot 
[image]

when viewed using `Web Developer Responsive design view`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This Might do it for you

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Lezwd21o/1/)

Comment: There's no Firefox/IE  equivalent to ' ::-webkit-scrollbar'